# onclick function using attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, onclick, alert

Trying to get an alert box on click, but it doesn't alert. when I try on my localhost. But it alerts on ***[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLb7c90a/)***. Why so?

My localhost code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css">
</head>
<body>

      <select id="right_option" class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Name</option>
        <option value="Alexa" data-tokens="Alexa">Alexa</option>
        <option value="John" data-tokens="John">John</option>
        </select>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[aria-owns='bs-select-1']").click(function(){
alert("click");
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your dev tools console for errors. Most chances are any of the libraries you're using (in particular, jQuery) are not loading.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work fine

Comment: @ludovico I checked dev tools console no warning and errors there...

Comment: @Echolot for JSFiddle it works, but when I try it on my localhost it doesn't for me

Comment: have you tried doing a console.log at the beginning of your ```$(document).ready(function() {``` ?

Comment: What is the result of $("[aria-owns='bs-select-1']").length ?

Comment: @xomunita I tried this on my local computer using the Live Server extension in Visual Studio Code

Comment: @JeroenHeier it's **0**

Comment: @ludovico you mean something like: `$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('Happens'); });`? If yes, console display *Happens*

Comment: So that's the problem. Review your selector. This should be > 0 in order to get any results.

Comment: @JeroenHeier the same codes and selector which I try at local gives length as *1* in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

looks like localhost is taking time to render try giving some time to registering the onclick listener. following code worked for me. try tweaking the timeout milliseconds argument.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(()=>{ 
$("[aria-owns='bs-select-1']").click(function(){
alert("click");
});}, 1000);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

      <select id="right_option" class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Name</option>
        <option value="Alexa" data-tokens="Alexa">Alexa</option>
        <option value="John" data-tokens="John">John</option>
        </select>
</body>
</html>
```